# Controls for show imagery in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I add the show imagery controls (which appear by default in Google Maps on the bottom right corner) to my map?

[image]

I've found nothing about it on the documentation page about controls. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro) and CSS for positioning